# Xamarin.Forms - MethodAccessException when calling InitializeComponent() inside main App ctor

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, .net-standard-2.0

I'm getting the following exception:

> System.MethodAccessException: Method
>   `Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Diagnostics.VisualDiagnostics.RegisterSourceInfo(object,System.Uri,int,int)'
>   is inaccessible from method`
>   GWallet.Frontend.XF.CS.App.InitializeComponent()'   at at (wrapper
>   managed-to-native)
>   System.Object.__icall_wrapper_mono_throw_method_access(intptr,intptr) 
>   at GWallet.Frontend.XF.CS.App.InitializeComponent () [0x00012] in
>   /Users/knocte/Documents/Code/geewalletFRONTENDbug/src/GWallet.Frontend.XF.CS/obj/Debug/netstandard2.0/App.xaml.g.cs:22
>   at GWallet.Frontend.XF.CS.App..ctor () [0x00008] in
>   /Users/knocte/Documents/Code/geewalletFRONTENDbug/src/GWallet.Frontend.XF.CS/App.xaml.cs:10
>   at GWallet.Frontend.XF.Android.MainActivity.OnCreate
>   (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x00022] in
>   /Users/knocte/Documents/Code/geewalletFRONTENDbug/src/GWallet.Frontend.XF.Android/MainActivity.fs:33
>   at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (System.IntPtr
>   jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr
>   native_savedInstanceState) [0x00011] in
>   <11f101b564894ca7af6c482ddc51c698>:0   at at (wrapper dynamic-method)
>   Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.7(intptr,intptr,intptr)

The App class is the typical simple one completely equal to one generated by the "hello-world" template of VS4Mac:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace GWallet.Frontend.XF.CS
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = Initialization.LandingPage();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/175308/new-error-coming-out-of-no-where-in-app-xamal-g-cs-plz-help

Comment: Firstly, delete the folder `bin` and `obj` both in forms project and  platform project, then clean and rebuild it. And also make sure all the projects in your solution are on the latest version of Forms .